# I need help with this painting

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image][image][image]

I found this painting online, is there any way to know who made it?

Comment: can you show me the full image. Maybe that will be helpful.

Comment: Yes, thank you, hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

The [regular script transcription](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B8%E5%AE%9A) looks like

[image: 朎]

> 朎
>
> This is probably an [art name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_name)

[image: 秵山]

> 秵山
>
> This is probably the artist's real name; also appears on the calligraphy as the last two characters
>
> [image: 秵山]

I cannot find any artists being referred to by these names.